# MFMailComposeViewController problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

So I have a MFMailComposeViewController that i call on when i click a button and i have an if statement that checks what a UILabel is equal to and if the device can send mail like this

```
if ([conditionlabel  isEqual: @"Fair"] && [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product:%@    Make:%@   Year Manufactured:%@  Description:%@  Condition:Fair Email:%@",inputProduct,inputMake,inputYear,inputDescript, inputEmail];
    NSArray *recipient = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"LoveShackElectronics@gmail.com"];
    MFMailComposeViewController *SuperLovedEmail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [SuperLovedEmail setTitle:emailTitle];
    [SuperLovedEmail setToRecipients:recipient];
    [SuperLovedEmail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [SuperLovedEmail setUserActivity:false];
    [self presentViewController:SuperLovedEmail animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and i have an else statement after this that makes an alert and shows it. But for some reason, it always returns false and just shows the alert even on a device that i know is signed in through the mail app and is able to send mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean `[conditionLabel.text isEqual:@"Fair"]`.

You are currently comparing the `UILabel` to an `NSString`. That will never be true. You need to compare the label's `text`.

One thing that would have helped was if you used `isEqualToString:` instead of `isEqual:`.

Also, you really shouldn't be checking a label's value. A label is a view. Views are not meant to be a source of data. You should have actual data you check.

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things that are the hardest to notice. Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue.